# Adobe Animate CC 2017. No user is signed in. Web fonts cannot be used

Tags: adobe, google-font-api

I'm trying to use google web fonts in Adobe Animate CC 2017. I'm following the steps in this article https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/google-fonts.html# , but when clicking the world icon and selecting google fonts a warning box pops up with the following text: "No user is signed in. Web fonts cannot be used".

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an isolated issue. I reinstalled adobe creative cloud and now everything works as expected.